# How to make a Dockerfile and run it for multiple Python files?

Tags: python, docker

So, I'm new to Docker. I want to use Ta-Lib and freqtrade libraries for a bot I want to build. The problem is that I don't want to build the Dockerfile over and over again. I have been copying my python code in the Dockerfile as shown below but as soon as I change the python code, I have to rebuild the Dockerfile because I changed the copied python script. Each build takes over 10 minutes to complete and this makes my life very difficult to test the bot. Is there a way that I build the Dockerfile with all the dependencies and requirements first and then simply run my script using the image made? So that I don't have to rebuild the entire thing just after adding one line of code?
The Dockerfile is as shown below

```
FROM python:3.8

COPY trader1.py ./

RUN pip install numpy 
RUN pip install python-binance
RUN pip install pandas
RUN pip install backtrader
RUN pip install matplotlib
RUN pip install websocket_client

# TA-Lib
RUN wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
  tar -xvzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
  cd ta-lib/ && \
  ./configure --prefix=/usr && \
  make && \
  make install

RUN rm -R ta-lib ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
RUN pip install freqtrade
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Because of the layer system Docker images are using a line that just deleted something is not going to give any space back. You should combine the call with the `RUN` before. Also copy your code as late as possible to take advantage of chaching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should copy your python file as late as possible.

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN pip install numpy 
RUN pip install python-binance
RUN pip install pandas
RUN pip install backtrader
RUN pip install matplotlib
RUN pip install websocket_client

# TA-Lib
RUN wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
  tar -xvzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
  cd ta-lib/ && \
  ./configure --prefix=/usr && \
  make && \
  make install

RUN rm -R ta-lib ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
RUN pip install freqtrade

COPY trader1.py ./
```

The docker containers are layered, every line is one layer, when recreating a container, docker rebuild the container only from the changing layer.

**Second, you could create a volume**
If you use docker-compose, you could create a volume in your current folder, or subfolder, in order to have your file automatically synced with your host. (then you don't need the COPY)

Answer (score -2):

You can mount the code as a volume, from then you only need to rebuild the docker image when the requirements are changed.

[Docker tutorial about volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)